# chosen.js destroy mCustomScrollbar on clear the search results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

This is the code that I used:

```js
$(function() {
  $('select.select').chosen({
    disable_search_threshold: 5,
    width: '50%'
  });
  $('select.select').on('chosen:showing_dropdown', function() {
    $('.chosen-results:visible').mCustomScrollbar({
      theme: 'minimal-dark',
      autoHideScrollbar: false
    });
  });
  $('select.select').on('chosen:hiding_dropdown', function() {
   if($(".chosen-results").length) {
    $('.chosen-results').mCustomScrollbar('destroy');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.chosen-drop .chosen-results {
  max-height: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.7.0/chosen.jquery.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.7.0/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select id="name" class="select">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="aaa">aaa</option>
  <option value="bbb">bbb</option>
  <option value="ccc">ccc</option>
  <option value="ddd">ddd</option>
  <option value="eee">eee</option>
  <option value="fff">fff</option>
  <option value="ggg">ggg</option>
  <option value="hhh">hhh</option>
</select>
```

The problem that when I trying to using the search box it's working without any issue but when I clear the search results the mCustomScrollbar to destroy and chosen.js also give me an error `TypeError: f[0] is undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below example

```js
$(function() {
  $('select.select').chosen({
    disable_search_threshold: 5,
    width: '50%'

  });


 $('.chosen-container').on('click', function() {
       
  $('.chosen-results li').wrapAll('<div class="chosen-dropdown"></div>') 
   $('.chosen-dropdown').mCustomScrollbar({
        theme: 'minimal-dark'
  })              
              
  });

});
```

```css
 .chosen-dropdown{
  height: 240px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.7.0/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.7.0/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select id="name" class="select">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="aaa">aaa</option>
  <option value="bbb">bbb</option>
  <option value="ccc">ccc</option>
  <option value="ddd">ddd</option>
  <option value="eee">eee</option>
  <option value="fff">fff</option>
  <option value="ggg">ggg</option>
  <option value="hhh">hhh</option>
  <option value="ccc">ccc</option>
  <option value="ddd">ddd</option>
  <option value="eee">eee</option>
  <option value="fff">fff</option>
  <option value="ggg">ggg</option>
  <option value="hhh">hhh</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The same issue tries a search for anything and clears the search results you will found that mCustomScrollbar destroy.